# Shortest Non-Shared Substring

Tags: string, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

We need to find shortest substring of `text_1` that doesn't appear in `text_2`. How to solve this problem using suffix and LCP arrays in `O(|text_1|+|text_2|)` time?

**UPD:**

I know how to solve it using suffix tree. Question is how to solve problem using [Suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) and [LCP array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array) alone (no other auxiliary data structures).

First we need to build generalized suffix array and lcp array of string `text_1$text_2#`. Then we have to perform linear scan of LCP array, finding start position and length of shortest substring unique to `text_1`.

The question is what we need to do during this linear scan of LCP arrray, to determine start position (using suffix array) and length (using LCP array) of unique substirng.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain how you can solve this problem through an approach I developed.

- Add a variable in every Node that will store that it is end_node or
  not. By end node I mean in suffix tree it doesn't have any child.
- Add a variable that will store it made by text1 or text2. For this,
  you can use the value of the variable that you are using to iterate
  text_1$text_2# during the creation of the tree.
- Now the approach is simple, suppose you are at some node.

  1. if this node is a leaf node(use the first variable). Return a pair of numbers "fir, 
      sec" fir=second variable(which stores the text number it is made from) and sec= 
      1.
  2. if a node is not a leaf node. iterate its every child and see:

     - if all the originated from the same child return pair of number
       "fir,sec". fir=text number with the child with min_length and
       sec=min_length
     - if any two-child originated from different text return pair of number 
       "fir, sec". fir=text number with the child with min_length and sec=min_length+1